# Can we convert any string date value to Date yyyy-MM-dd in java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a column called start_date in database and the field has a mapping in model class like

```
   @Column(name = "start_date")
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   Date startDate
```

and in my pojo the same field I have as

```
    String startDate;
```

from UI I am getting the string value and I want to convert that string to date and store into database

```
    modelObj.setStartDate(parse(pojoObj.getStartDate())
```

and here is the parse() method

```
   private Date parse(String dateValue){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateValue);
    return date;
    }
```

this code is working fine when I am providing date in yyyy-MM-dd format but not working in dd-MM-yyyy or yyyy-MMM-dd or MMM dd, yyyy any other format.
can I someone help me how can I persist the date field irrespective it's format.
As String I am able to store but I want to store it as date.

Comment: You cant you have to convert the string to a date like you do in the parse method.

Comment: Example: Date is May 6th 2020 input is 06-05-2020, but can also be 05-06-2020.
You can't possibly parse any date string into a date without more knowledge, for at least 30% of the dates you need more info. I suggest you restrict your UI by using some kind of datepicker or a very specific pattern and then validate the user input. Also maybe look into [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instead of Date

Comment: restricting the UI to accept/send the date as yyyy-MM-dd format (if possible )would be wise and it also saves lot of effort at the back end. If you are not sure of the formats that will come from UI then it will be a little hectic at middleware to handle the unknown date formats.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` doesn’t seem right for the formats you are giving.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a solution, the database uses BIGINT (20),and Pojo use "Long".

When saving to the database, use a timestamp of length 13, Only need to convert to timestamp when receiving the parameter, and convert the timestamp to any format when returning data.

Comment: yea that can be done but again I need to sort the db data on start_date, in that case I need to make the start_date column as date

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over all your date formats and try to parse the input to a date.

- If you can parse exactly one input to a date then you are fine.
- If you cannot parse the input, then you need to add a date format to your list.
- If you can parse the input to more than one date and the dates are not the same, then you need to think how to proceed :-D

  The code could look like

```
  private Date parse(String dateValue) {
    final List<SimpleDateFormat> simpleDateFormats = Arrays.asList(
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));

    final List<Date> dateCandidates = simpleDateFormats.stream()
        .map(formatter -> tryParse(formatter, dateValue))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        // check if there is more than one date
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (dateCandidates.isEmpty()) {
      throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unsupported date format %s", dateValue));
    }
    if (dateCandidates.size() > 1) {
      // check if all dates are the same, otherwise throw exception since your input is ambigious
    }
    return dateCandidates.get(0);
  }

  private Date tryParse(SimpleDateFormat formatter, String dateValue) {
    try {
      return formatter.parse(dateValue);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below  instead of TemporalType.TIMESTAMP

```
@Column(name = "start_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   Date startDate
```

Comment: Are you saying that simply changing the annotation will enable it to automatically parse any date string regardless of the format of that date string?